# Porting Outlook AD RMS credentials to another computer

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encryption, data-transfer, credentials

I have e-mails in Microsoft Outlook that have Active Directory Rights Management Service (AD RMS) Information Rights Management (IRM) on them.  Let's say this is on computer "A".  Computer "A" is on the network that has the AD RMS server, so it can authenticate and open the encrypted messages.  I need to copy these messages over to another computer, computer "B", which is not on the network with the AD RMS server, so it is unable to connect and get the credentials (e.g. the certificate) needed to open the encrypted messages.  Is there a way that I can manually copy/port the credentials that computer A's Outlook downloaded, and put them into computer B's Outlook, so that I can read and open the messages on computer B?  How can this be done?